# Convert system url categories

Tags: magento2.2, category, amasty

I have a store view:

```
 - Default
 - First store
 - Second store
```

The second store has a problem with the categories

First store - its URL looks like this: `firststore.com/category-name/`

when i go to the category Second store - its URL looks like this: `secondstore.com/directory/category/view/s/category-name/id/111/`

URL modules that should work with categories do not work correctly on the second store, tell me how to convert URLs to `secondstore.com/category-name/`

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 all url rewrite can be see on table     url_rewrite

```
(
    url_rewrite_id   int unsigned auto_increment comment 'Rewrite Id'
        primary key,
    entity_type      varchar(32)                 not null comment 'Entity type code',
    entity_id        int unsigned                not null comment 'Entity ID',
    request_path     varchar(255)                null comment 'Request Path',
    target_path      varchar(255)                null comment 'Target Path',
    redirect_type    smallint unsigned default 0 not null comment 'Redirect Type',
    store_id         smallint unsigned           not null comment 'Store Id',
    description      varchar(255)                null comment 'Description',
    is_autogenerated smallint unsigned default 0 not null comment 'Is rewrite generated automatically flag',
    metadata         varchar(255)                null comment 'Meta data for url rewrite',
    constraint URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID
        unique (request_path, store_id)
)
```

sometimes the easiest way is to manipulate the record
this 3 column that you need to modified entity_id, request_path, store_id

after that you need to reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```